# How to change the language of Joi package in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation, joi

I am using Joi (https://joi.dev/api/) for my React.js application to validate Forms.

but my problem is that the language of validation message is English.

How I can change the language of it?, My preferred language is Persian.

Answer (score -1):

just put that in a file and use it as your joi base :

Maybe this will help you:

var Joi = require('joi');
module.exports = Joi.options({ language: { ... } })

var Joi = require('./myOwnJoi');
var schema  = Joi.object()...

Comment: I get this error:     Error: "language" is not allowed